# Is the space of simple predictable processes topologized by uniform convergence metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, topological-vector-spaces

Im following the book by Protter on Stochastic Integration and he is currently introducing Semimartingales. In doing so he first introduces the class of simple predictable processes $S$ and then topologizes them with uniform convergence. As I understand it, this topology defines the closed sets as being those that are closed under uniform convergence, meaning that a set $C$ is closed iff for every convergent subsequence $((X_t^n)_{t \in [0,\infty)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_t |X^n_t-X_t| = 0$ and $X \in S$ one has $X \in C$. My topology background is not super strong so I was wondering, is this space metrizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protter's topology on $\mathcal{S}$ is induced by the norm (see p. 52)
$$
\left\|\|X-Y\|_{\infty}\right\|_{L^\infty}
$$
where the $L^\infty$-norm indicates an essential supremum over $\omega\in\Omega$ and the $\infty$-norm is the sup-norm over $t\in[0,\infty)$. Therefore, $\mathcal{S}$ is even a normed space, so in particular metrizable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm working with an old version of the book that does not explicitly mention this.